# State not updating with Map using StateNotifier of Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have an `itemCount` map with an `ItemDescription` keys and `int` values.

```
Map<ItemDescription, int> itemCount = {
  ItemDescription(
    name: 'Pepsi',
    price: 10,
  ): 1,
  ItemDescription(
    name: 'Coca-Cola',
    price: 12,
  ): 1,
};
```

I want to update the `int` value of the map in various places throughout my code, so I have defined the functions `increment` and `decrement` in a `StateNotifier`:

```
class ItemCountQuantity extends StateNotifier<Map<ItemDescription, int>> {
  ItemCountQuantity() : super(itemCount);

  void decrement(int index) {
    state.update(
      state.keys.elementAt(index),
      (value) {
        return --value;
      },
    );
  }

  void increment(int index) {
    state.update(
      state.keys.elementAt(index),
      (value) {
        return ++value;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The `StateNotifierProvider` for the above is defined as such:

```
final itemCountQuantity =
    StateNotifierProvider<ItemCountQuantity, Map<ItemDescription, int>>(
  (ref) => ItemCountQuantity(),
);
```

When I am calling `ref.read(itemCountQuantity.notifier).decrement(index);` or `ref.read(itemCountQuantity.notifier).increment(index);` in the `onPressed` parameter of a button, I can see that the value is updating but the state is not. Is there some error in my `StateNotifier`?

EDIT-1:

I tried setting the `StateNotifier` as such:

```
class ItemCountQuantity extends StateNotifier<Map<ItemDescription, int>> {
  ItemCountQuantity() : super(itemCount);

  void decrement(int index) {
    state = {
      ...state,
      state.keys.elementAt(index):
          state[state.keys.elementAt(index)]! - 1
    };
  }

  void increment(int index) {
    state = {
      ...state,
      state.keys.elementAt(index):
          state[state.keys.elementAt(index)]! + 1
    };
  }
}
```

But neither did this work.

EDIT-2:

This `StateNotifier` works for the first `increment`/`decrement` but not for any subsequent ones:

```
class ItemCountQuantity extends StateNotifier<Map<ItemDescription, int>> {
  ItemCountQuantity() : super(itemCount);

  void decrement(int index) {
    state = {
      ...state,
      state.keys.elementAt(index): state.update(
        state.keys.elementAt(index),
        (value) {
          return --value;
        },
      )
    };
  }

  void increment(int index) {
    state = {
      ...state,
      state.keys.elementAt(index): state.update(
        state.keys.elementAt(index),
        (value) {
          return ++value;
        },
      )
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you’re missing:

```
state = Map.of(state.update(…));
// instead of just
state.update(…);
```

This is because you need to assign the state to a new value so the StateNotifier knows something was updated. (state is implemented as a getter and setter under the hood.)

However, I’d like to note that doing state.keys.elementAt(index) feels very wrong when using a map, as it relies on the implementation of the map. If you must use the index to access an element, use a list of tuples. Or, just reference the map using its keys (and not an index).

Comment: I just tried this right now, it didn't work, saying `The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<ItemDescription, int>'.`, although that is a common error.

Comment: The reason I referenced the map using its index is because I'm using an `itemBuilder` with a `ListView` to display the map.

Comment: @raptron in that case, you should convert the map into a list of tuples instead of using the map. But in any case, the edit you made to your post with the state = {…} should trigger any providers/consumers dependent on your state. Was it a syntax issue you were getting there?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any syntax error, even I'm confused on how to proceed further and rectify the issue altogether. And I wasn't aware tuples were a data type in Dart, I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: @raptron tuples are not native in dart (yet), but there is [a package](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple) providing support for tuples.

Comment: @raptron how is `ItemDescription` defined? Does it override hashcode and equals? Do you make it with freezed or similar?

Comment: And one more check: are you using `final varName = ref.watch(itemCountQuantity);` directly in your UI in the build method?

Comment: It's just a vanilla implementation of `ItemDescription`, with instance variables and standard constructors with named parameters. And I'm also using the `ref.watch(itemCountQuantity)` directly in the `build` method.

Comment: Do you explicitly override hashcode and equals in ItemDescription? If not, that could be an issue when dealing with a Map (and would be fixed if you switched to a list of tuples when referencing by index).

Comment: I don't override anything actually; so if you think there might be an issue with usage of Map for Riverpod I could raise an issue on GitHub. Yeah, i'll try tuples and see

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with Map/Riverpod. I think the issue is that Map relies on its keys' `hashcode` and `equals` implementation, and it's possible that something funky is going on when you are trying to update the state because your ItemDescription does not override these methods. If you used `freezed` to create the `ItemDescription` class, this may not be an issue. See here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html

Comment: Yeah, that was a very nuanced detail you fished out. I'll definitely experiment with the scope of using either `freezed` or Tuple. Thank you for your overall input!